# Como ingresar una fecha nula en FoxPro mediante C#

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

Estoy desarrollando una app que se conecta a tablas de FoxPro, necesito saber como ingresar una fecha nula en esa tabla FoxPro, estoy empleando C# y este es el codigo que he hecho, que no funciona.

```
conexion.Open();
        string comandoSql = "UPDATE YTBRESER SET Skipass = ?, Emitida = ?, Femision = ? WHERE Idbtickets = ?";
        OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(comandoSql, conexion);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "");
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", false);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", OdbcType.DateTime);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", idbTicket);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexion.Close();
```

Comment: Podrías detalla un poco más el problema? Por qué no funciona el código ese, te da un error? No hace lo que esperas?

Comment: @cpistiner Ya lo solucione no te preocupes

Comment: me alegro, si podes compartinos la solución así queda para otros, gracias!